# How to use the HttpServletRequest in @Service or @Dao layer to get the user presented credentials?

Tags: spring-boot

I have implemented the security layer in my project using Spring Boot. Now,I would like to know how to get the request parameters using `HttpServletRequest` in `@Service` or `@Dao` layer. I tried some way to get the request parameters and I could the username and password but I need to pass that in the Dao. My code:

**Security Layer code:**

```java
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest request; 

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    UserDetails userDetails;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        request.getParameter("username");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/index.html","/home.html","/static/*","/home/*", "/login.html","/login").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        http.formLogin().usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").loginProcessingUrl("/login/authenticate").successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
        http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
        http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).invalidateHttpSession(true);
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());

        // CSRF tokens handling
        http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenProcessingFilter(), RequestFetcher.class);
    }

    /**
     * Configures the authentication manager bean which processes authentication
     * requests.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // Dao based authentication
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder());
    }

    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new AccessDeniedHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                    AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
                response.getWriter().append("Access denied");
                response.setStatus(403);
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * This is used to hash the password of the user
     * when we need to use BCrypt.
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }

    /**
     * This bean is load the user specific data when form login is used.
     */
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new MyCustomUserDetailsService(userDao);
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestFetcher tokenProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
      RequestFetcher tokenProcessingFilter = new RequestFetcher();
      tokenProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
      return tokenProcessingFilter;
    }

}
public class RequestFetcher extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter{

    private String userName = "";
    private String password = "";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = this.getAsHttpRequest(request);
        userName = httpRequest.getParameter("username");
        System.out.println("===Username===" +userName);
        password = httpRequest.getParameter("password");
        System.out.println("===Password===" +password);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private HttpServletRequest getAsHttpRequest(ServletRequest request){
        if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Expecting an HTTP request");
        }
        return (HttpServletRequest) request;
    }


    public String getUserName(){
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName){
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Could anybody please help me to get the request parameters?

Comment: You shouldn't... You don't want nor should tie your service layer or dao layer to the web layer. Also your `RequestFetcher` is dangerous it will not behave correctly with multiple concurrent requests. There is only a single instance imagine what happens if multiple requests come in, what would the value of `username` and `password` be.

Comment: @M.DeinumI agree.But, how to use the HttpServletRequest or some other concept to get the username and password.I have used the spring security http.formLogin() to process the login request so in this case i couldn't get the username and password.Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: And why would you need the username/password? The login and authentication is handled by Spring Security if you want to tap into that implement the right interfaces. If you need the user in your own service use the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` to obtain the current `Authentication` (i.e. the current user).

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, the login authentication is handled by spring security.But, i need of raw password that user has entered.I have used the MD5 encryption to validate the user and i have one more separate ldap server to check the user with raw password.We could obtain the user credentials using SecurityContextHolder.getContext() once the user has been authenticated but i need here before authenticating the user.

Comment: Why are you checking yourself, that should be the responsibility of Spring Security which then handles all that.

Comment: @M.Deimun I have the scenario to validate the user in two DB servers.In one database i have the password encrypted using the MD5 so i can handle this login authentication with spring security.If the user not exists in this DB i'll look on another db used the ldap to validate the user with username and raw password.What i need is even if spring boot security handle the login auth.Why can't we get the raw password ?

Comment: You still have the raw password and what you explain is that you only need 2 authentication providers. Spring Security can do all that for you with you need to hack around...